# Is it ok to have different links leading to the same resource?

Tags: hateoas, hypermedia, hal-json

**Option 1:**

We **always** return "absolute" links (no nesting). That way we always give to the client the same link for a given resource.

```
{
    "employeeName": "Joe"
    "links": {
        "company": [
            { "href": "http://api.com/companies/1" }
        ]
}
```

Is it needed? (knowing that it requires extra work on the server side)

**Option 2:**

We may also return "relative" links, nested under the resource returned to the client (here employee). But now the client may have received 2 differents links ("http://api.com/companies/1" and "http://api.com/employees/4/company") corresponding to the same resource.

```
{
    "employeeName": "Joe"
    "links": {
        "company": [
            { "href": "http://api.com/employees/4/company" }
        ]
}
```

Is there a better option than the other and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to have multiple links to same resource.

URL design is irrelevant in HATEOAS.

Comment: Thanks Denis. Would you mind sharing resources confirming what you are saying?

Comment: That resource is a book:
RESTful Web APIs
By Leonard Richardson, Mike Amundsen, Sam Ruby
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028468.do?sortby=publicationDate